# PowerShell Script Count of Files in Directory

Tags: powershell

I was trying to get the count of file in a directory using Powershell script

```
$k=(Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\count files" -file -Recurse -Include *.txt | Measure-Object).count 
Write-Output $k
```

This was the command I am trying, I am getting the count but with the directory as well I need only the count, not the directory so could you help me with this

[image: This was output I was getting]

Comment: I'm confused, I only see the count in the picture link. Are you referring to it displaying that the ps1 is being ran?

Comment: "with the directory as well" - that's not output, that's the prompt

Comment: The `| Measure-Object` command at the end is unnecessary. This would be a more helpful answer for the op if you explained the code.

Comment: Are you just after `Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\count files" -file -Recurse -Include *.txt | Measure-Object | select count`     ?